# check user exist mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the following table

```
uId | groupId
==============
1     12
3     66
```

How can I write a mySQL statement to check if a user exists in a group?

**What I've Tried**:

```
SELECT FROM usertable(uId) WHERE usertable.uId = $uId
```

the above query only checks if the user exists but doesn't check whether the user belongs to a particular group.

Comment: I think I'd start with a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Just append that condition to your `where` clause, for example:

```
SELECT uId
FROM usertable
WHERE usertable.uId = 1
AND groupId = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `groupId` parameter to your query `WHERE` clause.

```
$userId = x; // some user id
$groupId = y; // some group id

$con; // your mysqli instance

if (!$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM usertable WHERE uId = ? AND groupId = ?')) {
    throw new Exception($con->error, $con->errno);
}

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $userId, $groupId);

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
}
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // user exists and is in group
}
```

Comment: @user3522722 Yes, this is more secure. Are you seriously complaining about a total of nine lines of *mysqli* code that secures your query from SQL injection and provides error checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("Select from usertable(uId) where usertable.uId = $uId and groupId=$gid");

if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0){
echo "user exists!";
}else
{
echo "user not exists!";
}
```